# i cant access the database

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, session

i'm making a login form the data of the users is on the database but every time i try to login it cant access and i dont know what is wrong in my php code can anyone help me in this pls guys 
i think there's nothing wrong with the connection but the error i got is "wrong password"

the php code

```
     if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

  $dbServName = "localhost";
  $dbuser = "root";
  $dbPassword = "";
  $dbname = "formlab2";
  $conn=mysqli_connect($dbServName,$dbuser,$dbPassword,$dbname);

  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $password=$_POST['Password'];

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=? AND password=?;";
 $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql)) {
  echo "error";

}


else{

  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"ss",$email,$password);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  $result= mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
  if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $pswcheck = password_verify($password, $row['password']);
    if ($pswcheck == false) {
      echo "WRONG PASSWORD";
    }
    else if ($pswcheck == true) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['userID']= $row ['user_id'];
        header("location: ../wel.php");

    }

  }
           }

         }
```

Comment: @Bravo honestly im new to database i didnt get what you mean

Comment: @Bravo  i think there's nothing wrong with the connection but the error i got is "wrong password"

Comment: *the error i got is "wrong password"* ... you mean *WRONG PASSWORD*, because that's what your code does ... I notice you use `$_POST['email']` and `$_POST['Password']` ... does your form submit `email` and `Password` ... or does it submit `email` and `password` (this is why I, in a deleted comment, asked to see the client side code) - cAsE is imPortant :p

Answer (score 0):

for connecting to a db i use this:

```
<?php
$DB_HOST = 'localhost';
$DB_USER = 'root';
$DB_PASS = 'root';
$DB_NAME = 'name-of-db';
// $DB_PORT = '8889';
$link = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
//$link = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME, $DB_PORT);
if ($link->connect_error) { 
   die('Connect Error ('.$link->connect_errno.') '.$link->connect_error);
}
$link->set_charset('utf8');
```

i noticed you hid your db password but if you are working in localhost it should just be root, in case you have something else. also to make it easier for yourself you could have this code in a seperate file and user either "include" or "require" to insert the code into the page. then you can include the file on multiple pages easily.

then for the login process:
so its not the database connection but the login process?
try adding session_start at the top of the document.
this is how i have made a login before, maybe it helps you:

```
$sql = 'SELECT id, pwhash FROM tablename WHERE username=?';

            $stmt = $link->prepare( $sql );

            $stmt->bind_param( 's', $un );
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result( $id, $pwhash);
            while ( $stmt->fetch() ) {
            if ( password_verify( $pw, $pwhash ) ) {
                $_SESSION[ 'uid' ] = $id;
                $_SESSION[ 'uname' ] = $un;
}
```

some small differences. i have an if statement at my password_verify. try that.

Comment: every time i login with an email and a password saved in the database it gives me wrong password @hndvf

Comment: im new to stackoverflow and adding comments here is horrible. i will edit my original post instead. @codiins